# WSDL2Apex limitations

Tags: wsdl2apex

I am trying to generate Apex classes from WSDL. I was given a zipped file with one WSDL and three SXD files. After pretty much I've tried it all including consulting with Salesforce I have the final version of WSDL. I passed parsing finally and tried to generate Apex class again, now I got a different error:

> Apex Generation Failed. Unable to find element for {http://svc.kp.org/hp_admn/mbr_admn/addr_validate/v2}getAddressValidationResponse

You can see the WSDL here https://gist.github.com/Miroandme/public.

I do not have a lot of experience with external application WSDLs and am not sure how to handle this part.

Comment: Not sure how to submit WSDL here. Looks like my file is too long. I wonder if I can attach the file.

Comment: You could do pastebin or a github gist, if you think it'll help. If it's that big though, I'm not sure we're going to be able to help, but we can at least take a look for you, in case it's something obvious.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Miroandme/public

Comment: Above is my public Gits where WSDL can be reviewed.

Comment: Your WSDL as linked is invalid. 

It uses a `trnheader:` namespace for certain element types which isn't defined as a xmlns in the document. If you can share the unmodified WSDL it will likely be easier to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

This tool [WSDL Parser and Apex Generator](https://www.fuseit.com/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer.aspx#pos_1890) that is part of the FuseIT SFDC Explorer includes:

> Support for complex types that extend from a base class <xsd:extension
>   base="tns:Sample">

which is one of the things that is probably tripping up the standard Salesforce tool. See [An alternative to Salesforces Wsdl2Apex for calling SOAP web services in Apex](http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/03/an-alternative-to-salesforces-wsdl2apex.html)
 from Danial Ballinger's blog for some history on this work.

Some of these capabilities may have made it into this [open source WSDL2Apex project](https://github.com/forcedotcom/WSDL2Apex) as Daniel contributed to that.